# ngOnChanges only detecting change when cursor is moving

Tags: angular

I have an input on an Angular2 directive which contains a variable being updated on an interval.

The issue i'm finding is that if a cursor is not being actively moved it stops detecting change and only resumes detecting again when the mouse resumes movement. I have to imagine there is a way to fire a function whenever the @Input is changed without any interaction from a cursor?

**The Directive**

```
@Input('current-beat') currentBeat: number;
ngOnChanges() {
  this.update();
  console.log('changed detected', this.currentBeat);
}
```

**HTML Tag markup**

```
<div my-instrument-beat-changer [current-beat]="sequencerSettings['beat']">
```

**The function in the Service that Updates the currentBeat**

```
// function called when a web worker set on an interval
// posts a message to the service
setBeat(time: number, beat: number) {
    this.sequencerSettings['beat'] = beat;
}
```

Comment: ngOnChanges get called when input is changed.

Comment: Please provide more context. How is `currentBeat` updated?

Comment: A service updates a JSON object with the beat every time a webworker set on an interval communicates with it. The JSON object is then used for the input. It works perfect when the mouse is moving. ngOnChanges just won't fire on the Input value change alone.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, ngOnChanges won't fire just on value changed alone, you can use ngZone to fire it.

Inject `NgZone` and use on value set.

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

setBeat(time: number, beat: number) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.sequencerSettings['beat'] = beat;
  });
}
```